# css first-of-type not working?

Tags: html, css

I have a page of questions and each questions has a `h5` title to it. To add some space I added a `margin-top` to the titles, however I do not want the margin on the very first title. It just looks weird.

I've been trying to remove it by using `h5:first-of-type` but I can't seem to get it to work. Am I doing something wrong?

```
.questionnaire h5:first-of-type{
  margin-top: 0;
}

.questionnaire h5{
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

the html looks like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
  </label>
  <p>these are words here</p>
</div><!--.form-group-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
  </label>
  <p>these are words here</p>
</div><!--.form-group-->  
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
  </label>
  <p>these are words here</p>
</div><!--.form-group-->  
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
  </label>
  <p>these are words here</p>
</div><!--.form-group-->  
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
  </label>
  <p>these are words here</p>
</div><!--.form-group-->  
<div class="form-group">
  <label>
    <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
  </label>
  <p>these are words here</p>
</div><!--.form-group-->
```

Comment: Need to see your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

`:first-of-type` refers to the direct parent. If you've got intermediate elements, it'll "reset" your counter. Example to illustrate the problem :

```css
.questionnaire h5:first-of-type{
    margin-top: 0;
    color: red;
}
.questionnaire h5{
    margin-top: 2em;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="questionnaire">
    <h5>Title 1</h5>
    <h5>Title 2</h5>
    <h5>Title 3</h5>
    <div>
        <h5>Title 4</h5>
        <h5>Title 5</h5>
        <div>
            <h5>Title 6</h5>
            <div>
                <h5>Title 7</h5>
            </div>
            <h5>Title 8</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
    <h5>Title 9</h5>
    <h5>Title 10</h5>
</div>
```

---

Instead, use `first-of-type` on your `.form-group` :

```css
.questionnaire .form-group:first-of-type h5 {
    margin-top: 0;
    color: red;
}
.questionnaire h5{
    margin-top: 2em;
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="questionnaire">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
      </label>
      <p>these are words here</p>
    </div><!--.form-group-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
      </label>
      <p>these are words here</p>
    </div><!--.form-group-->  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
      </label>
      <p>these are words here</p>
    </div><!--.form-group-->  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
      </label>
      <p>these are words here</p>
    </div><!--.form-group-->  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
      </label>
      <p>these are words here</p>
    </div><!--.form-group-->  
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>
        <h5><span class="asterisk">*</span>required</h5>
      </label>
      <p>these are words here</p>
    </div><!--.form-group-->    
</div>
```

Comment: Thats why I can't figure out why this isn't working. It's reading my css, but crossing out the .questionnaire h5{
    margin-top: 2em;
    color: blue;
} and only taking the .questionnaire h5:first-of-type{
    margin-top: 0;
    color: red;
}

Comment: @zazvorniki This is probably caused by intermediate elements.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying not to do though...I just want the very first one to not have a margin...not the rest.

Comment: @zazvorniki I edited my answer to show you a way to target your first `h5`.

Answer (score 0):

HTML code

HTML

```
<div class="questionnaire">
    <h5>Title 1</h5> <!-- first-of-type -->
    <h5>Title 2</h5>
    <h5>Title 3</h5>
    <h5>Title 4</h5>
    <h5>Title 5</h5>
    <h5>Title 6</h5>
    <h5>Title 7</h5>
    <h5>Title 8</h5>
    <h5>Title 9</h5>
    <h5>Title 10</h5>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.questionnaire h5:first-child{
    margin-top: 0px;
   background-color:#066; color:#fff;
   }

.questionnaire h5{
    margin-top: 2em;
    color: blue;
}
```

working fine.. Title 1 apply any property
in css

Comment: This doesn't work for my example above though where I have the h5 within elements and then trying to grab the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/j67y371c/

```
 .form-group h5:first-of-type{
      margin-top: 0px !important;
    }

    .form-group h5{
      margin-top: 2em;
    }
```